# How to get the original URL called in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have a lambda setup with the proxy integration in API Gateway.

I can call my lambda with a URL like https://7kbw9fcfa4.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/foo The path here is `/dev/foo`.

However if I set up CloudFront in front of that, the URL becomes https://a45ex7tnds5r5o.cloudfront.net/foo and the path is `/foo`.

In both cases I have the same keys in the `event` variable:

- `path` contains `/foo`
- `requestContext.path` contains `/dev/foo`

How can I get reliably the actual URL that the client sees in the browser? (both when using Cloudfront and when using API Gateway directly)

Comment: Have you tried looking at origin header? Also Did you enable headers from CloudFront to API Gateway. If you don't whitelist the headers, you will not get them from CloudFront.

Comment: @Kannaiyan I whitelisted all headers except the `Host` header because it is recommended not to forward it (else it messes up the Cloudfront -> API Gateway connection). The `Origin` header doesn't seem to be useful as it contains only the domain name, not the path (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin).

Answer (score 1):

You could [configure your CloudFront distribution to use a custom header](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginCustomHeaders) that would be passed to the Lambda function. Then you could determine whether to use `path` or `requestContext.path` based on if that CloudFront-only header is present.

Comment: That is not good in my case (see the details in the question) because when I use CloudFront the URL in the browser is `/foo`, not `/dev/foo`. Yet (and this is the problem) the variables in `event` are the same, with CloudFront or not. So there's no way to know if it's going through CloudFront or not.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding; I see what you mean now. I've updated the answer to better address the question.

Comment: Thanks, you got it! That is an interesting answer and it would work! Ideally I'd like to find a "more automated" solution because it is for an open source project so I'd rather avoid asking users to create a specific CloudFront header every time (see https://github.com/mnapoli/bref/issues/67). If you have any insight that would be awesome! In any case thanks for the idea!